# Can you find your location in $\mathbb{Z}$ using least prime factor?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, factoring

Suppose you have a semi-black-box function:

$$f(x):=\mathrm{lpf}((N+x)^2+1)$$

where $\mathrm{lpf}$ means least prime factor, and $N\in\mathbb{Z}$ is some constant which you do not know.

You can use this function as much as you want with whatever values of $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ you want. My question is, assuming that $N$ is a finite integer value, and there's no trickery going on, is it possible to determine the value of $N$ with a finite amount of function queries?

Comment: There's no finite limit, at least in my conception. Yes, I thought about it for a bit and I have an idea, but I was waiting to see what other people had to say first.

Comment: Since you have $N\in \mathbb{Z}$, $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, you need to define $\mathrm{lpf}(1)$ (in case that $N+x=0$). If you insist on using integers and if you define this to be for example $1$ (a common definition), then this problem has a simple solution.

Comment: @Sil: indeed! Just go through all possible values of $x$, in increasing order of absolute magnitude. As soon as you find $x$ with $f(x)=1$, you have the solution $x=-N$. (But I suspect the OP is asking for an absolute bound on the number of queries, which is surely impossible.)

Comment: @TonyK Right, there is even more efficient way though (working conditionally) - by using $\mathrm{lpf}(p)=p$ for primes $p$, so we can get $N=\sqrt{f(x)-1}-x$ while verifying $f(-N)=1$, which will work automatically once we hit a prime $(x+N)^2+1$  but it assumes there are infinitely many primes of form $n^2+1$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: If we know $|N|\le M$, then we only need at most $2M+1$ tries, namely one for each possible value of $N$. (Or does this count as many?) And in practice we can get by with fewer checks than this, because each check typically rules out more than one possibility.

Comment: I think OP should also clarify if he means constant bound for number of steps or if the bound can depend on $N$ (but still be finite).

Comment: @Sil I'm not sure what bound you're referring to. That said, the simple solution was the one I arrived at. As near as I can tell, that minimum is the single point that's not ambiguous out of the entire set.

Comment: Totally unbounded, just needs to be finite; I wanted to rule out any solutions which rely on infinitely many trials.

Comment: @Trevor Might be worth updating in the original post then, and same with $\mathrm{lpf}(1)$ described above. In this configuration it has simple solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way utilizing that $x,N \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathrm{lpf}(1):=1$ (second part might need additional clarification by OP, but without it the function would be undefined so assuming this is a natural definition).

As mentioned in comments, we have $f(-N)=1$ and this is the only value of $x$ for which $f(x)=1$ - for all other values we have $(N+x)^2+1>1$ and so it divisible by at least one prime. So we just need to try all $|x| \leq |N|$, which takes finite amount of queries, at most $2|N|+1$.

This can be improved significantly by using the fact that upon hitting $(N+x)^2+1$ a prime, we have $f(x)=(N+x)^2+1$, and so $N=\pm\sqrt{f(x)-1}-x$. So whenever $f(x)-1$ is a square and one of two resulting $N$'s satisfies $f(-N)=1$, we can terminate. This speeds up the searching significantly for large $N$, but still needs to be combined with previous approach which guarantees it will terminate (otherwise the algorithm would rely on assumption that there are infinitely many primes of form $n^2+1$ - which is an open problem).

Comment: As I said, that was the answer I'd arrived at too. As for the strategy, I have a clarification question: how do you know when you've hit a prime? My understanding is that given only the lpf to use, anything that "looks like" a prime could be a repetition of the whole region some far distance away from where the actual prime is.  e.g. How do I know if lpf(f(6))=37 is truly prime, or I'm really taking lpf(f(6+37#))...

Comment: You don't need to check for prime, because the verification by $f(-N)=1$ that follows suffices by itself for whole problem. The hitting prime by itself is more of a theoretical importance here, to see that this shortcut will work, but the $f(x)=1$ is the actual condition that is important. Or you could flip it around, and when you hit $f(-N)=1$, you will know you have hit a prime previously, since only for primes it could have worked (having $\mathrm{lpf}((N+x)^2+1)=(N+x)^2+1$), but still you will not utilize this fact in any way, the algorithm will still finish.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $N$ is known to be in an interval of length $M$.  The primes will never be $3\pmod4$.  Suppose there are $K$ other primes whose product is at least $M$.  Run through in order:

1) try $x=0$ and $x=1$ to find whether $N$ is even or odd.
2) try five $x$, avoiding $f(x)=2$, to find $N\pmod5$.
3) try thirteen $x$, avoiding $f(x)\le5$, to find $N\pmod{13}$ and so on.

I think it takes about $O((\ln M)^2/2\ln \ln M)$ steps.

Edit:  The following method takes at most $O(2\ln M/\ln\ln M)$ steps.

Let $A,B,C$ be three bins to put numbers in.  Bin $A$ is for primes that have not yet appeared as $p=f(x)$.  Bin $B$ is for primes that have appeared once, and bin $C$ for primes that have appeared twice.
After $n$ steps, $N\pmod p$ can be one of at most $p$ different values for each $p\in A$.  $N\pmod p$ can be one of two values for each $p\in B$.   $N\pmod p$ is known for each $p\in C$.

Take the first $K$ prime numbers of the form $4q+1$.  $K$ is large enough that twice the product of these primes is at least $M$.  Put them all in bin $A$.
Let $x_1$ be any number.  Now, for each step:
Let $p_n=f(x_n)$
1) If $p_n$ is in bin $B$, move it and all smaller primes in $B$ to bin $C$.
2) If  $p_n\in A$, move it to bin $B$.
3) For each prime $p\in A, p\lt p_n$, rule out values of $N\pmod p$ that would have made the square+1 a multiple of $p$.  If there are two values left, move $p$ to $B$. If there is one value left, move $p$ to $C$.
4) If $p_n$ is in neither bin, and is odd, place $p_n$ in bin $B$, and move any primes $p\in B, p\lt p_n$ to $C$.
5) In the first step, put $2$ in bin $C$.

Choose $x_{n+1}$ according to its remainders modulo every prime in the bins.
6)  If $p\in A$, make $x_{n+1}\pmod p$ different from all those that have been ruled out in step 3.
7) If $p\in B$, there are two possible values for $N\pmod p$.  Choose $x_{n+1}$ so that the square+1 is a multiple of $p$ for one of those options.
8) If $p\in C$, make sure the square+1 is not a multiple of $p$.

Stop when the product of the primes in $C$ is at least $M$.  If $P$ is the largest of the original $K$ primes, the process stops in at most $2P$ steps.